# InsufficientPermissions fetching analytics goals (JAVA API)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I have a strange behaviour retrieving profile goals via Java google analytics API.

The problem randomly happens.
Sometimes, when I call

```
analytics.management().goals().list(accountId, webpropertyId, profileId).execute();
```

it returns

```
{

"code" : 403,

  "errors" : [ {

    "domain" : "global",

    "message" : "User does not have permission to perform this operation",

    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"

  } ],

  "message" : "User does not have permission to perform this operation"

}
```

If I wait for some seconds and repeat the same instruction it works fine.
The problem does not happen every time (very strange for a permission problem).
It happens randomly on random profiles

Can anyone help me?

Comment: with which version of API you trying to get the data.Show your code how you are fetching the data.Have you registered the email in your google analytics account [as admin level user]?

Comment: Are you using your Java application to retrieve the accountId, webpropertyId, profileId or are those hard coded? If they are hard coded it is likely that the application user is simply not authorized to access the goals associated with that account, property or view (profile)